# How can I filter out custom rules from Azure WAF logs?

Tags: azure-waf, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am using the following query to monitor Azure WAF, it works fine but I want to filter out custom rule hits from the query and only show blocks by MSFT Default Rulesets but I cannot find how to do that

The following query show blocks from custom rules AND MSFT default rules, I want to only show MSFT default rule set blocks

I understand I can exclude the name or all my custom rules but that will be difficult to maintain

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK" and Category == "FrontdoorWebApplicationFirewallLog"
| where action_s == "Block"
| where requestUri_s contains "xxx" or requestUri_s contains "xxx" or requestUri_s contains "xxx" or requestUri_s contains "xxx" or requestUri_s contains "xxx" or requestUri_s contains "xxx"
| extend ParsedUrl = parseurl(requestUri_s)
| summarize BlockCount = count() by TimeStamp = bin(TimeGenerated, 3h), ClientIP = clientIP_s, RuleName = ruleName_s, Host = host_s, PATH = tostring(ParsedUrl.Path)
| order by TimeStamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Azure Frontdoor premium WAF? If yes, according to [Azure Frontdoor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-monitor?pivots=front-door-standard-premium#:%7E:text=The%20following%20example%20query%20shows%20the%20requests%20that%20were%20blocked%20by%20the%20Front%20Door%20WAF%3A) , the Category is "FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallLog" and not "FrontdoorWebApplicationFirewallLog" (Notice the uppercase 'D' in Frontdoor)

That said, you can exclude custom rules by looking for only the Default Ruleset

```
AzureDiagnostics
|where ResourceType == "PROFILES" or ResourceType == "FRONTDOORS"
| where action_s == "Block"
| where Category == "FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallLog"
| where ruleName_s contains "Microsoft_DefaultRuleSet"
```